# Getting coordinates of an ExcelRange object

Tags: delphi, excel, com

In Excel's COM API:

Given an `ExcelRange` object, how would I determine which rows and columns are contained within it?

I do not want the *contents* of the range, just the "coordinates" of the range, preferably as integers.

I did notice that `ExcelRange` has both a `Row` and a `Column` property, however these only indicate the row and column of the upper left corner of the range.

Note:  I am using Delphi, however this question could be relevant to any language using Excel though COM, so answering using Delphi is not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming a simple rectangular range then you use the `Rows` and `Columns` properties of the `ExcelRange` object. The top-left of the selection is determined by `Range.Row` and `Range.Column`. The number of selected rows and columns is given by `Range.Rows.Count` and `Range.Columns.Count`.

In complete generality an Excel range can be made up of multiple non-contiguous areas. In this case you use the `Areas` property of `ExcelRange` to iterate through the simple rectangular ranges that make up the complex range.

To illustrate consider the following code:

```
procedure DescribeExcelRange(const Range: ExcelRange);
var
  AreaIndex: Integer;
  Area: ExcelRange;
begin
  for AreaIndex := 1 to Range.Areas.Count do
  begin
    Area := Range.Areas[i];
    Writeln(Format(
      'Area %d: R%dC%d:R%dC%d',
      [AreaIndex, Area.Row, Area.Column, 
       Area.Row+Area.Rows.Count-1, Area.Column+Area.Columns.Count-1]
    ));
  end;
end;
```

I have not actually tested this code so I hope I have remembered correctly that indexing is 1-based.